# Parse error in 'test/step_definitions/requester.js': (1:1): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty

Tags: javascript, api, automation, endpoint, cucumberjs

I am developing an API automated test case using cucumber and JavaScript and I am getting this error:

```
Error: Parse error in 'test/step_definitions/requester.js': (1:1): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got '//const fetch = require('node-fetch');'
```

I have a .feature file within 'features' folder.
In addition, I have two .js files within 'step_definitions' folder. Files are 'my_steps' and 'requester.js'.

The Gruntfile.js contains this line to run it:

```
command: './node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js /features/*.feature -r /Users/alfredo.bazo/XCore-ContentLibrary-Tests/API-Test/test/step_definitions/*.js',
```

As per error thrown, it seems that requester.js file is considered as a feature file. Why? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52150612/cucumber-js-parse-error-when-run-on-jenkins